# EntityFramework 6 Database.SqlQuery connection resiliency

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, azure, resiliency

I know that from version 6 EntityFramework supports connection resiliency feature when working with SQL Azure database. I am pretty sure it applies to DbSet context members.

But what if I want to execute SQL query against the database like that:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<User>("select * from Users");
```

Is it safe to perform this operation like that? Do I need to use any `Retry` frameworks here? I guess no, but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: Yes.

Long versions: 
The connection resilience is applied on the `IDbConnection` level. That direct sql query only generates a new `IDbCommand` that will be delivered to the sever by the same `IDbConnection` as all the others.